# DataGridView Row select without RowHeaders

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How do you select the whole DataGridView row on cell select and disabling the selection of a single cell

NOTE: just like the behavior of a listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by `gridView.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect;`

That still leaves the option for the user to select (edit) a cell by clicking twice, you'll have to experiment (with Editing and ReadOnly) to get it like you want.